# Alter table add column as select statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle9i

How to do something like this...

```
alter table customer_schedule add (week_number as (TO_CHAR((SCHEDULE_DATE),'iw'))
```

Wherein SCHEDULE_DATE is one of the existing columns in table

Comment: Why do you want to store a derived value in table?

Comment: I want to develop a form wherein when week number is selected it should populate a list from another table. I did the same thing by using month but now i want it with week number.

Comment: whats the error you are facing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is where you need **VIRTUAL COLUMN**.  If you are on 11g and up, you could certainly do -

```
alter table table_name
add (column_name [data_type] [generated always] as (column_expression) [virtual]);
```

In your case, it will be something like -

```
alter table customer_schedule add (week_number data_type generated always as (TO_CHAR((SCHEDULE_DATE),'iw') VIRTUAL)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time and response but its not working

Comment: You did to much copy/paste from documentation, it must be `alter table customer_schedule add (week_number NUMBER generated always as (TO_CHAR(SCHEDULE_DATE,'iw')) VIRTUAL);`

Comment: @Wernfried, I intentionally left the data_type for OP to decide ,because number '03' will be just considered as 3 and not 03. OP did not mention he wants it to be a number field.

Comment: @Kimaya, pleasemention your database version. Post results from `select * from v$version where rownum = 1`.

Comment: Its:- Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.1.0 - Production

Comment: Then you cannot use virtual column, it was introduced in 11gR1. You  need to create a trigger.

Comment: Thank you. I will have to use trigger then.

Answer (score 2):

On 9i, you cannot use *virtual columns*, so I'd probably go with a view:

```
create view customer_schedule_view as
    select 
      c.*,
      to_char(c.schedule_date, 'iw')) week_number
    from
      customer_schedule c;
```

Of course, in your forms you need then to select from the view rather from the table.

Answer (score 0):

The default keyword is supposed to let you store values when there is some value missing, but due to restrictions, [you cannot use a column name](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402)

> A DEFAULT expression cannot contain references to PL/SQL functions or **to other columns**, the pseudocolumns LEVEL, PRIOR, and ROWNUM, or date constants that are not fully specified.

I think a row-level BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE trigger should do want you want to do.

Comment: All that is previous century. Virtual columns were introduced in 11g.

Comment: I asked OP to provide version details. If OP is on 11g prior databases, trigger will be the only solution.

Comment: Don't know why someone downvoted your answer, I don't see anything to be downvoted. And upvote from my side.